# limitation in the callback function in nodejs redis?

Tags: redis

I am not sure if the issue I am having is a limitation in redis itself or in the nodejs 'redis' module implementation.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(6379,'192.168.200.5');

client.on('error',function (error) {
    console.log("** error in connection **");
    process.exit(1);
});

client.on('connect',function () {
    console.log("** connected **");

    client.on('message',function (channel,message) {
        if (channel == 'taskqueue') {
            console.log(channel + ' --> ' + message);
            var params = message.split(' ');
            var inputf = params[0];
            var outputf = params[1];
            var dim = inputf.split('_').slice(-1)[0];

            client.rpush('records',message,function (e,reply) {

            });
        }
    });

    client.subscribe('taskqueue');
});
```

From the code snippet above, I tried to do an RPUSH inside an "ON MESSAGE" subscription event. It does not work, and I get a client 'ON ERROR' event, thus, it prints error in connection. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: After further searching, I came across this page https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/365 which seems to explain the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

After further searching, I came across this page https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/365 which seems to explain the scenario.